# get outlook single occurrence of recurring calendar event from double click on calendar

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am creating an outlook plugin that opens a SharePoint Calendar event for editing. The SharePoint Calendar is added to outlook as an overlay.

When clicking on the `series` event and editing a `series` everything works fine. But when I select just this one (occurrence). I am unable to get any of the properties for the `AppointmentItem` object.

I have tried both the `ReadComplete` and the `Open` events and still get an exception:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040108" and I am unable to access the
>   Parent. It appears all of the properties are null except Class = 26
>   and MessageClass = "IPM.Appointment"

```
    private void Application_ItemLoad(object item)
    {
        _item = item;
        try
        {
            if (!(item is AppointmentItem) || !_exp.CurrentFolder.Name.Contains("Test - Conference Room ")) return;
            _warnUser = true;
            _apptItem = (AppointmentItem) item;
            _apptItem.ReadComplete += test;
            _apptItem.Open += McAI_Open;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

           var expMessage = ex.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(expMessage);
        }
    }

    private static void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Note: Outlook no longer raises this event. If you have code that 
        //    must run when Outlook shuts down, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506785
    }

    private void McAI_Open(ref bool cancel)
    {
        _warnUser = false;
        var conferenceRoom = _exp.CurrentFolder.Name;
        conferenceRoom = conferenceRoom.Replace("Test - ", "");
        if (!(_item is AppointmentItem)){return;}
        try
        {
            var g = _apptItem.IsRecurring;
            if (_apptItem != null && _exp.CurrentFolder.Name.Contains("Test") && _apptItem.Location != null)
            {
                var location = _apptItem.Location;
                var result = location.Substring(location.LastIndexOf(':') + 1);

                cancel = true;
                var sharePointItemId = int.Parse(result);                   
                var frm = new FrmCalendarSelection(
                    "<SharePointURL>" + conferenceRoom,
                    sharePointItemId);
                frm.Show();
                frm.Closed += Frm_Closed;
            }
            else if (_apptItem != null && _exp.CurrentFolder.Name.Contains("Test") && _apptItem.Location == null)
            {
                cancel = true;
                var frm = new FrmCalendarSelection(
                    "<SharePointURL>" + conferenceRoom);
                frm.Show();
                frm.Closed += Frm_Closed;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What line of code exactly fires the exception in the code?

Comment: it throws an error  on this line  "if (_apptItem != null && _exp.CurrentFolder.Name.Contains("Test") && _apptItem.Location != null)"